# Как добавлять блоки с рекламой google adsense ajax-ом?

Tags: ajax, google-adsense

Есть страница на которой при прокрутке загружается контент аяксом, среди этого контента есть блоки с рекламой google adsense. Проблема в том, что не могу добавить эту рекламу.

Вот изначальный код которым я пользуюсь.

```
<ins 
    class="adsbygoogle" 
    style="display:inline-block;width:271px;height:398px" 
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-9426180910051973" 
    data-ad-slot="4707289646">
</ins>

<script>

    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

</script>
```

Но когда пытаюсь загрузить аяксом ничего не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вот эта часть кода как-раз загружает рекламу асинхронно, т.е. "аяксом".

`(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

После добавления блока с рекламой запускайте этот код и реклама добавится в недостающие блоки.